# Microsoft BotFramework Transcript Logging Timestamp Format

Tags: timestamp, botframework, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm using Microsoft BotFramework and logging all the transcripts from the chatbot into an Azure blob storage container.

The timestamps on each message is of a format I can't recognise so I'm having to store them as strings for now. I'd like to transform and store them as a proper DateTime format using Azure Data Factory so I can improve my chatbot's analytics.

The timestamps look as follows:

```
2019-08-07T09:19:45.342Z
2019-08-07T09:19:39.582Z
2019-08-07T09:19:57.637Z
```

What DateTime format are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is UTC also called Coordinated Universal Time and follows the International Standard for the representation of dates and times as specified in ISO 8601. You can read more about it from the W3 website [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks Steven - this is what I thought but I was getting an error every time in ADF when trying to set the DateTime format as `'u'`. I found out that you have to set the format as a custom format as follows for it to work: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ`